# Is it possible to avoid specifying a default in order to get an X in Chisel?

Tags: hardware, hdl, synthesis, digital-logic, chisel

The following [Chisel](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/) code works as expected.

```scala
class Memo extends Module {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  val io = new Bundle {
    val wen     = Bool(INPUT)
    val wrAddr  = UInt(INPUT,  8)
    val wrData  = UInt(INPUT,  8)
    val ren     = Bool(INPUT)
    val rdAddr  = UInt(INPUT,  8)
    val rdData  = UInt(OUTPUT, 8)
  }
  val mem = Mem(UInt(width = 8), 256)
  when (io.wen) { mem(io.wrAddr) := io.wrData }                                                                                                                                                                                                
  io.rdData := UInt(0)
  when (io.ren) { io.rdData := mem(io.rdAddr) }                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

However, it's a compile-time error if I don't specify `io.rdData := UInt(0)`, because defaults are required. Is there a way to either explicitly specify `X` or to have modules without defaults output X, erm, by default?

Some reasons you might want to do this are that nothing should rely on the output if `ren` isn't asserted, and Xs let you specify it, and specifying an X can tell the synthesis tool that it's a don't care, for optimization purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chisel does not support X.

This is probably what you want:

```
io.rdData := mem(io.rdAddr)
```

(this prevents muxing between zero and mem's readout data).

If, for example, one is trying to infer a single-ported SRAM, the Chisel tutorial/manual describes how to do so (https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/latest/chisel-tutorial.pdf):

```
val ram1p =
  Mem(UInt(width = 32), 1024, seqRead = true)
  val reg_raddr = Reg(UInt())
  when (wen) { ram1p(waddr) := wdata }
  .elsewhen (ren) { reg_raddr := raddr }
  val rdata = ram1p(reg_raddr)
```

In short, the read address needs to be registered (since we're dealing with synchronous memory in this example), and the enable signal on this register dictates that the read-out data only changes with that enable is true.  Thus, the backend understands this a read-enable signal exists on the read port, and in this example, the write port and the read port are one and the same (since only one is ever accessed at a time).  Or if you want 1w/1r (as per your example), you can change the "elsewhen (ren)" to a "when (ren)".

Answer (score 1):

From the [Chisel 2.0 Tutorial](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/latest/chisel-tutorial.pdf) paper, only binary logic is supported at the moment:

> #### 2 Hardware expressible in Chisel
>
> This version of Chisel also only supports binary logic, and does not
>   support tri-state signals.
>
> > We focus on binary logic designs as they constitute the vast majority
> >     of designs in practice. We omit support for tri-state logic in the
> >     current Chisel language as this is in any case poorly supported by
> >     industry flows, and difficult to use reliably outside of controlled
> >     hard macros.

Comment: Ahh, the part where they say they focus on binary logic only answers the question. But, X is distinct from tri-state. Tri-state means that you're not driving anything at all, whereas, X represents an unknown value. Unlike tri-state, it's widely used in industry.

I wonder if I can write a post-processor to the Verilog Chisel emits to substitute X in cases where I want an X.

Comment: True.  Edited for clarity.  A constructor of X values to support explicit assignment would be a nice feature.